# Dictionary value replace

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Imagine I have a dictionary like this:

```
d = {'1':['a'], '2':['b', 'c', 'd'], '3':['e', 'f'], '4':['g']}
```

Each key of the dictionary represents a unique person of a certain class.
Each key must have only one value.
Key's with one value represent the correct reassignment.
Key's with more than one value represent the possibilities. One of those values is the most correct for that key.

I have a processed list with the most correct value.

```
LIST = ['c', 'e']
```

I must now iterate values of `LIST` through values of dictionary when `len(values) > 1` and replace them to look like this:

```
d = {'1':['a'], '2':['c'], '3':['e'], '4':['g']}
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly LIST contains preferred values. Do you need to worry about keys having multiple possibilities with none of them in LIST? What about when multiple possibilities are in LIST? Is that possible?

Comment: You will get answers because this is fun and easy, but for a good SO question you need to show what you have tried

Answer (score 2):

Initialise your correct values inside a `set`.

```
correct = {'c', 'e'}
# correct = set(LIST)
```

Now, assuming list values with more than one element can have only a single correct element, you can build a dictionary using a conditional comprehension:

```
d2 = {k : list(correct.intersection(v)) if len(v) > 1 else v for k, v in d.items()}
print(d2)
# {'1': ['a'], '2': ['c'], '3': ['e'], '4': ['g']}
```

If there can be more than one possible correct value, you can take just the first one.

```
d2 = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    if len(v) > 1:
        c = list(correct.intersection(v))
        v = c[:1]
    d2[k] = v

print(d2)
# {'1': ['a'], '2': ['c'], '3': ['e'], '4': ['g']}
```

---

If you meant to mutate `d` in-place (because making a full copy can be expensive), then the above solution simplifies to

```
for k, v in d.items():
    if len(v) > 1:
        c = list(correct.intersection(v))
        d[k] = c[:1]

print(d)
# {'1': ['a'], '2': ['c'], '3': ['e'], '4': ['g']}
```

Comment: I can't initialise it. Previously I had L (LIST):
L = list(set(repeated_expert_values))
processed_expert_values.sort()

If I just make L = set(repeated_expert_values)
then I cant sort them.
'"AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'sort' "

Comment: @JoãoNunes You can always just do `correct = set(LIST)` instead. That shouldn't have to be a dealbreaker for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach in one statement using `dict comprehension`:

```
d = {'1':['a'], '2':['b', 'c', 'd'], '3':['e', 'f'], '4':['g']}
a = ['c', 'e']

output = {k: v if not any(j in set(a) for j in v) else list(set(v) & set(a)) if v and isinstance(v, (list, tuple)) else [] for k, v in d.items()}

# More readeable like this:
# {
#    k: v if not any(j in set(a) for j in v) else list(set(v) & set(a))
#       if v and isinstance(v, (list, tuple))
#           else [] for k, v in d.items()
# }
```

print(output)

Output:

```
{'1': ['a'], '2': ['c'], '3': ['e'], '4': ['g']}
```